# Is there any way to get data type of XMLHttpRequest on base controller in .net core 3.1

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

**Here is any Jquery ajax POST request;**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Customers/GetAll",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

**Here is my Controller Action Method which requested by ajax above;**

```
public IActionResult GetAll()
{
    //Method body...
}
```

How can I get the `dataType` of any ajax request in base controller or action method?

Answer (score 1):

Try to get `accept` in headers:

[image]

action:

```
 public IActionResult GetAll()
        {
            string dataType = HttpContext.Request.Headers["accept"].ToString();
            //Method body...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The headers can be retrieved on the HttpContext object.

```
if(HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("accept", out var acceptHeaders)) {
   var firstAcceptHeader = acceptHeaders.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

You can also access the header value using indexing `Headers["accept"]`, but be aware, that if there is no accept header, for whatever reason, this will throw a NullReferenceException.